# How to retain Conductor's router object during activity re-create?

Tags: android, android-activity, conductor

Let say I have a Conductor's Router lives inside an Activity. The Router is holding 4 Conductor's Controller inside it.

When I re-create my activity by changing the locale for example.

Is this possible I can somehow retain the Router for my activity after it's re-created?

I know about the saveInstanceState and restoreInstanceState of activity but since Router is neither implementation of Parcelable nor Serializable. So, those method are not the option here. :(

Comment: consider saving the object in your viewmodel ?

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that too but the view model's life is attached to activity's life. So when the activity is killed it also die too.

Comment: can you share your activity and `Conductor's ` class code?